# SQL Persist command is giving an Error in IBM Watson studio Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, sql, websphere, ibm-watson

I am tryin to run a SQL magic command in IBM Watson studio and i am receiving below error. Need support to resolve error. Image is attached.  SQL Persist Command Errored.
[image: 1]

I am new to Watson Studio and unable to resolve it.
Best,
Arslan

Answer (score 2):

Try  `%sql --persist chicago_socioeconomic_data`

I am taking the same course as you and I found very useful information [here](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql#ipython-sql).